# In Windows 10, how can we find out which applications reserved TCP port ranges as shown by netsh?

Tags: windows-10

Recently in my development machine some TCP ports started being unavailable for applications, giving the error 10013.

Searching the internet I think that this explanation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/error-10013-wsaeacces-is-returned) is the most likely: the ports were administratively excluded by some application(s), most likely being reserved for their own use.

Indeed I can see the ranges of excluded ports with the command

```
netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

I can also try to delete some excluded ranges, but mostly netsh refuses to do so, showing errors "access denied" (even inside an administrative shell) or "element not found".

So, now I would like to try another approach: find out which applications are excluding those TCP port ranges.

Although this is a corporate machine, it does not belong to a Windows domain (and indeed is in my house right now, as I'm working from home because of the pandemic).

So, that's the question: how can I find which applications are reserving those TCP port ranges ?

---

UPDATE

There are lots of questions about this in Stackoverflow (which I think is not the adequate place for this question, but anyway).

I found a solution somewhere that worked for me:

```
net start winnat
net stop winnat
```

It worked immediately, didn't even require a restart.

Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.804 Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

---

Edit.

Output from netsh just now:

```
$ netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange tcp
                                    
Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges      
                                    
Start Port    End Port                  
----------    --------                  
     20092       20191                  
     20192       20291                  
     20292       20391                  
     20392       20491                  
     20492       20591                  
     20592       20691                  
     20792       20891                  
     20892       20991                  
     20992       21091                  
     21092       21191                  
     21192       21291                  
     21292       21391                  
     21393       21492                  
     21493       21592                  
     21593       21692                  
     21693       21792                  
     21793       21892                  
     21893       21992                  
     22033       22132                  
     22133       22232                  
     22233       22332                  
     22637       22736                  
     22737       22836                  
     22837       22936                  
     22937       23036                  
     23037       23136                  
     23137       23236                  
     23237       23336                  
     23360       23459                  
     23460       23559                  
     23560       23659                  
     23660       23759                  

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is usually caused by Hyper-V, Docker, or WSL. Try restarting `winnat`:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Also according to [docker/for-win#3171 (comment).](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-554587817) it happens when the dynamic port range on your machine is not updated to the new start port. You can fix this with:

```
netsh int ipv[46] set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
```

Answer (score 1):

A very good tool to relate Port to Application is TCP View (which is a Microsoft SysInternals app).

Look for SysInternals, download TCP View, install it and run it. It will show you what you need.

Here is a screen shot .

[image]

In the Options section, you can uncheck (do not show) unconnected ports.  That removes svchost, for example, and reduces some display clutter.

Comment: I do know TCPView, but I use mostly netstat, which gives (mostly) the same information. Anyway I've run TCPView now (after I restarted my machine), and it shows me that Firefox is using lots and lots of ports (which is fine, I have lots of open Firefox windows and tabs) ... it's not really the answer to my question, but points to a possible culprit (though I would think Firefox would have to ask for admin privileges if it wanted to reserve TCP port ranges) ... thanks for your answer

Comment: Many apps use lots of ports and that is why I suggested TCP View.  I also use Comm View for this but that is not free. Very good however.

Comment: Also, I see there are lots of ports being used by Windows (svchost.exe) I don't know what for, and also by the F5 VPN tool, which was (or maybe still is) my prime suspect

Comment: You can use Options to not show Unconnected Endpoints and svchost goes away. So it (like other tools) can be managed.